# I need to pass a variable from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a plugin called `form` in which I get two data `val1` and `val2` and this is passed to a plugin called `route` and this must be passed to the `game` plugin, my variables reach the parent but then I can't pass it to the child plugin called game. Please help me or give me some guides to do it.

The variable `var1` is that I rescue and I must pass to the game.

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
    this.localVar1 = "";
  }

  datosDeFormInicio = (var1,var2) =>{
    this.localVar1 = var1;
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/juego">
            <Juego localVar1={this.localVar1} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Inicio datosDeFormInicio = {this.datosDeFormInicio}/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>  );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Reactjs, you can use redux to pass a value to other components, It's state management in Reactjs. However, you can use `https://github.com/facebookarchive/emitter` for simple.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use state instead of that variable. You'll need to add localVar1 to the state object you have `this.state{localVar1: ""};`

### How

You'll need to use `this.setState()` in `datosDeFormInicio()`

```
    datosDeFormInicio = (var1,var2) =>{
        this.setState(localVar1: var1);
    }
```

Usually, I would call this function setLocalVar1, but it's just a naming convention.

### Why

To lightly explain why yours won't work: it has to do with the order that React updates components, and `setState()` triggers the parent component to rerender, which is why you won't directly assign an object to the state variable

(`this .state.localVar1 = someVar` also doesn't trigger the rerender`)

Here is the link to setState in the React docs, for a more detailed explanation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for the answer, I followed the steps using a state, but still it does not pass me the localVar variables in the component Juego, the empty variables arrive.
This is the code you make.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {localVar:'',localVar2:''}
      }
      datosDeFormInicio = (var1,var2) =>{       
         this.setState({localVar: var1,localVar2:var2});
      }
 render() { 
    return (
      <Router>
          <Switch>
              <Route path="/juego">
                <Juego localVar={this.state.localVar} localVar2={this.state.localVar2} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/">
                <Inicio datosDeFormInicio = {this.datosDeFormInicio}/>
              </Route>
          </Switch>
      </Router>  );
  }
```